# Opening chrome in jenkins node(ubuntu) showing an error

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have a Jenkins server(master) and a node(slave) machine. The node machine is Ubuntu 20.04. The node is configured in the Jenkins server with the connection **Launch method** as **Lunch agents via SSH**.

I have a Jenkins job for automation using Selenium which should open the chrome browser, load URL, and run perform test.

While running my Selenium test in the Node via Jenkins, the chrome browser(GUI) can not be opened and the following error is returned.

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

However, running my selenium test using headless chrome works perfectly fine.

Can anyone please help me with how to run Chrome GUI in Jenkin's Node?